# Why is CSS matrix3d rendered faster than CSS position?

Tags: javascript, html, css, matrix

Let's say I want to to move an element from left to the right, I can achieve this by doing

```
 transform: translate3d(200px,0,0);
 /*or*/
 transform: translateX(200px);
```

or

```
 transform: matrix3d(x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,200,x,x,x)
```

or just set `left position`.

Why is CSS matrix3d rendered faster than just setting a position **left/top**?
[image]
[image]

UPDATE:

[CSS animation of top/left vs transform in slow-mo.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-62uPWUxgcg)

[high performance animations on HTML5](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/)

Comment: You should add which browser you're talking about, because there is no requirement to make matrix3d faster than setting `left`. However, my guess would be that it's because setting `matrix3d` turns on hardware acceleration with your browser.

Comment: Did your read the explanation of the bars? `operations per second (higher is better)`

Comment: @t.niese i didn't see that thank you

Comment: Anyway many of the tests on jspref are meaningless as they are created the wrong way and test something else then what was intended. Writing good performance test isn't an easy task, so always take care when you look at those. I don't think that the given results really reflect the actual render performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 factors than are relevant here

1) Because left can potentially affect all the layout in your page, so it forces a recalculate of style and layout. Transforms do not need this step, the transforms do not afect the element neighbours.

see [html5 - high performance animations](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/) for a better explanation

2) Because most 3d work is handled by the GPU and not by the CPU. The GPU not only can do that much faster, it also frees the CPU to handle better the rest of the work. You will see a lot of times the style

```
transform: translateZ(0px);
```

wich obviously does nothing, but that makes the broser use the GPU and accelerates the process. You could try to measure changes to left with this line added and see what the perfomance is.